# Build Errors with SimpleElastix on MacOS

Tags: elastix

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TM4NH.png)
I'm learning about Registration, so I wanted to install SimpleElastix for learning and experimenting, but have been unsuccessful in doing so.

Mac OS 14.1
Python 3.8

Could anyone help me and tell me what I should do to fix it.

Comment: What versions of cmake, Xcode (clang), and the SimpleITK source code are you using.  I was able to build SimpleElastix with cmake 3.28, Xcode 14.2 (clang 14.0) and the latest version of SimpleITK from Github.

Answer (score 0):

If you're encountering build errors with SimpleITK or SimpleElastix on macOS, it could be due to missing dependencies or issues with the build configuration. Ensure you have CMake, Xcode Command Line Tools, and required libraries installed. Check SimpleITK and SimpleElastix documentation for specific instructions and troubleshooting tips. If the issue persists, provide more details or error messages for further assistance.

Comment: Thank you! I think I already have CMake, Xcode Command Line Tools, and the required libraries. I also followed the official installation instructions. The detailed error message is shown in the figure above.

Comment: The answer is generic and doesn't really answer the question.  While the formatting of the original question could be better, the specific error messages were provided in the picture.  The picture also makes it clear that some of the basics mentioned in the answer have already been done.  E.g. You can't get to 83% without having XCode and CMake already installed.  The answer could be improved if the required libraries were specified or specific links to the site that contains said libraries were included.  The content as is would make a better comment to the question vice an answer.